# Cognos BI 8 Report Studio - Line Chart (x axis limitations)

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-bi

I'm creating a line chart in RS where total dollars is on the Y axis and year/month is on the x axis. There are currently three years of data (36 months) and I believe that because the chart is too large to load on one screen, Cognos is skipping some of the month labels. I have changed the Label Control (Frequency) value to 1 (to load labels at intervals of 1) yet it still skips months (currently loads 1,3,5,7 etc). Is there a way of forcing Cognos to display each of the months? Bearing in mind I have set the chart size to 100%, and anything beyond that won't work as scroll bars don't appear to allow complete viewing of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

change label control to automatic, then set allow skip to no. Set dimensions in pixels too, it doesn't like %